# How formal or euphemistic is "debris"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, informal-language, formal-language, euphemism

Is the word "debris" considered to be an euphemism of other words? And does the word have some kind of the degree of formality? If yes, is it informal or formal one?

So the word 'debris' here is in the clause "if you find my home in the debris"

Answer (score 1):

No, "debris" is not generally a euphemism.

Although many locutions in English are categorized as formal or informal and although some words are considered impolite or slang, individual words in English are seldom divided into formal and informal categories. "Debris" is neither slang nor impolite. It is, however, a word that may not be in the **active** vocabulary of many native speakers.